# Balanced Payments doesn't seem to work with Phonegap

Tags: balanced-payments

We are not able to call balanced.card.create from a Phonegap application. This is reproduced in a stock Phonegap application here: https://github.com/kevg/phonegap-balanced. Full details are in the README.md on github, but the basic summary is:

> For those not familiar with phonegap, the main page that loads is
>   index.html. This initializes phonegap in index.js. When the device is
>   ready, we will show a hidden DIV with a button named "Execute
>   Balanced." When you click this button, app.executeBalanced in index.js
>   will be called which prompts for the balanced marketplace URI, loads
>   balanced.js with $.getScript, and then calls balanced.card.create with
>   a test credit card.
>
> The expected result is that callbackHandler is called or an exception
>   is caught. Instead, it seems the execution of the Javascript thread
>   disappears into balanced.card.create, never to return and without any
>   error.

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: I should add that all external requests are [white listed](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) in [config.xml](https://github.com/kevg/phonegap-balanced/blob/master/phonegap-balanced-app/www/config.xml#L52), and this is in fact how balanced.js is able to load fine, so I don't think it's that type of issue. Also, in our real app, if we redirect the phonegap browser to our https:// website and then call balanced.card.create, things work fine (but then we leave file:///.../index.html and therefore can't access the phone APIs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, I found the bug in balanced.js. So, in Phonegap, window.location.href returns something like file:///.../index.html. Balanced.js creates an iframe to something like https://js.balancedpayments.com/proxy#file

```
var src = proxy + "#" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
```

https://github.com/balanced/balanced-js/blob/master/src/utils.js#L48

In the script returned in proxy.html (which I can't find on github), it does:

```
c.parentURL=decodeURIComponent(
    window.location.hash.replace(/^#/,"")
  ).replace(/#.*$/,"")
c.parentDomain=c.parentURL.replace(/([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/,"$1")
```

The regex doesn't match because file: has three slashes. Now, at first, I thought I could just convert the regex to:

```
/([^:]+:\/+[^\/]+).*/
```

However, then there's another problem, because balanced does a security origin check on the match:

```
if (d.origin.toLowerCase() !== c.toLowerCase()) return !1;
```

However, the regex returns file:///firstcomponent, whereas [event.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage#The_dispatched_event) does not include a host name for the file scheme, so these won't match even with a fixed regex.

I can't change anything in the script returned in the proxy response because if I load that from a domain other than balancedpayments.com, then the AJAX POST fails (return code 0 with a blank body). Therefore, the only thing I can control is the hash passed to the iframe.

However, since this regex is a replace, we can simply pass exactly what we know we need (we don't care that the regex is a no-op).

Therefore, the solution is to change L48 above to:

```
var src = proxy + "#" + encodeURIComponent("file://");
```

This works.

Comment: Hey, @Infofinity - thanks for this explanation. I'll have this taken looked at it today.